# How to use CA issued certificate with intermediate certificate in simplesamlphp as SP?

Tags: php, simplesamlphp

I'm trying to configure simplesamlphp SP to use a CA signed certificate (it's an IDP requirement) but can't get it to work, there's no documentation about it and I couldn't even find anything online.

So far I tried bundling the certificate and the intermediate into a bundle but the SAMLRequest signature is invalid if I do that. If I use it without intermediate the signature is valid but the cert cannot be verified.

Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: Your issue is the certificate is invalid or you're struggling to use the certificate in this library? Two separate topics.

Comment: I need to use it in this library in a way that the certificate can be verified (which cannot be done without intermediate certificate).

Comment: Again, that doesn't narrow it down. Is your certificate valid? Or are you having an issue with the library verifying your certificate? If so, show you what you're doing so we can self-replicate. Otherwise, you're better to tell us your steps to generate your certificate.